# Exponential inequality(Proof)

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function

**Given** $\forall x,y>0$
**Prove that** $x^y+y^x\ge1$

I have tried weighted inequalities and Jensen's but unfortunately ended up no where.
Please help me. (I know this is a basic inequality).

Comment: Can you take log on both sides of an inequality?

Comment: @AksharGandhi How would taking the logarithm facilitate here?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\geq1$ or $y\geq1$ the inequality is obviously true.

But for $\{x,y\}\subset(0,1)$ easy to show that $x^y\geq\frac{x}{x+y}$ 
and we are done!

Comment: Michael, it is easy to show that the inequality $x^y\ge \frac{x}{x+y}$ holds.  And the conclusion is trivial thereafter.  But, what inspired you to use this inequality?

Comment: @Dr. MV 27 I think you solved one problem or maybe two in math. We do it by the following reasoning. What's enough to get for the proof? Since $\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{x+y}=1$, it's enough to prove that $x^y>\frac{y}{x+y}$, which is wrong. The rest it's for you.

Comment: First, I find your sarcastic tone highly offensive.  You have not even come close to answering the question.  What motivated you to pursue the solution using that specific inequality?  There are a lot of ways to decompose $1$ into the sum of functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy $f(x,y)=g(y,x)$.

Comment: @Dr. MV It was a joke. Of course, there are very many ways. If to try, so we can find a right way.

Comment: That still didn't answer the question.  I suspect that you'd seen this development or a similar one and simply applied it.  And that's perfectly acceptable.  All of us borrow what we've seen.  ;-) -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV Now your tone is not good. I found this proof by myself, but indeed, around 30 years ago. By the way, in this forum there are very many my own inequalities, and copies of my solutions of another inequalities. I understand this situation. You are unfair to me.

Comment: Then just answer the simple question.  What inspired you to appeal to this inequality?

Answer (score 0):

**Case I:** $x$ and $y$ both greater than 1
$x^y, y^x > 1$
Hence, proved

**Case II:** x is 1 (without loss of generality)
$x^y$ = 1
$1 + y^x > 1$
Hence, proved

**Case III:** $x$ and $y$ both less than 1.
I can explain why this could be true informally. For both x and y less than 1, the power is actually a root, and a root of a number less than 1 will increase its value.
Still, can't show that it will be at least one.

Comment: For $\{x,y\}\subset(0,1)$ see my statement.