# How to prove $a^{b}+b^{a} \geq 1$ for all $a, b \geq 0$?

Tags: inequality

It is clear if $a \geq 1$ or $b \geq 1$, but how can I show it when $0< a,b <1$?

I want hints.

Comment: Maybe try Bernoulli’s inequality.

Comment: Bernoulli is a good start. As a hint for how this ends (which requires intermediate work), show that $ a^ b \geq a/(a+b)$, hence the result follows.

Comment: @Sahaj  thank you, I will try.

Comment: @CalvinLin    I will do the intermediate work, thank you, the beauty of learning lies in trying and putting efforts not getting the solution without trying.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381090/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319578/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1977318/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E%7Bb%7D%2Bb%5E%7Ba%7D%20%5Cgeq%201%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 <a<1$ and $0 < b < 1$ then $\frac1b > 1$ then $$b^{a-1} = \left(\frac1b\right)^{1-a} \ge 1 \ge 1-a$$ this implies $$b^a \ge b(1-a)$$ Finally, $$a^b + b^a \ge (1-(1-a))^b + b(1-a) \ge 1$$